# SQL Server : how to properly detect that row value has changed in specific column and order the output by another one?

Tags: sql-server, left-join, sql-order-by, row-number

I'm trying to detect row changes and the row number they occur, ordered by a certain column (date).

Here is the query I'm using:

```
WITH x AS 
(
   SELECT 
       *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date ASC) 
   FROM 
       [dbo].[DB]
)
SELECT 
    x.var1, x.var2, x.date, x.rn as RN, x.var3 
FROM 
    x 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    x AS y ON x.rn = y.rn + 1 AND x.var1 <> y.var1 
WHERE 
    y.var1 IS NOT NULL
```

However, the output I get is not always the same. Sometimes the data is ordered by date, sometimes it's not. Also, I don't always get all the row changes.

What might be wrong here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Two things:  the output could be in any order since you haven't specified an order by on the select from the CTE (X). 2nd... Unless date is UNIQUE (which I doubt since you specified a row_number on it) you need other criteria which uniquely identify a record in your order by  fro the row_number analytic to maintain a consistent order.  Consider `order by date asc, row_number` on your "Select from the cte (x)" and additional criteria to the `(order by date asc)` such that each record would be sorted uniquely.  then unless data changes, you're order should remain consistent.

Comment: Can you explain what you exactly mean by detecting row changes here?

Comment: I'm new to SQL. Could you give me an example of should I change my query? Thank you a lot @xQbert!

Comment: By detecting row changes I mean:

1 - A  2 - A  3 - A  4 - A  5 - B  6 - B  7 - B  

The column has changed at row number 5 @TheEsisia!

Answer (score 0):

Example...

```
WITH x AS (
   SELECT A.*
        , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date, var1, var2, var3 ASC)
   FROM [dbo].[DB] A)

SELECT x.var1, x.var2, x.date, x.rn as RN, x.var3 
FROM x 
LEFT OUTER JOIN x AS y 
  ON x.rn = y.rn + 1 
 AND x.var1 <> y.var1 
WHERE  y.var1 IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY Date, RN
```

The `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date asc, var1, var2, var3 ASC)`  could have any fields after `date asc` which uniquely identify a record in the table.

The problem is when the system orders db.date several records have the same date.  since you've not specified any order for these other records, the system is free to put them in any order; thus you can get different rownumbers on records each run.

And since you've not specified `order by date, rn` on outer query, those results could come back in any order as well.

Comment: Actually, date is UNIQUE, but I don't know any other way to get the output I want.
Besides, when I use the ORDER BY Date, RN on outer query, the query is executing for "infinite".


xQbert do you have any other suggestion to help me?